# chartjs-plugin-streaming + chartjs-plugin-zoom

Tags: plugins, streaming, chart.js, zooming

(sorry for my english)
I use chartjs-plugin-streaming for the real time chartjs and I want to use the chartjs-plugin-zoom.

But the zoom don't work.

When i test to zoom, appear the zoom area but on i leave the mouse from chart, nothing is happening

I see that the method `doZoom` of `chartjs-plugin-zoom` is called, then i think the problem is in streaming plugin, but I do not know where exactly.

I tested to call pause streaming before to do the zoom but there is the same problem.

What can I do to make the zoom work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chartjs-plugin-streaming v1.6.0 now supports chartjs-plugin-zoom.

Include Chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom.js, chartjs-plugin-streaming.js and required libraries (Moment.js and Hammer.js), and add `pan` and `zoom` options. Note that unlike other scale types, the `rangeMin` and `rangeMax` options don't specify time values. Instead, `pan.rangeMin` and `pan.rangeMax` limit the range of the `delay` option value while `zoom.rangeMin` and `zoom.rangeMax` limit the range of the `duration` option value.

```js
options: {
    // Assume x axis is the realtime scale
    pan: {
        enabled: true,    // Enable panning
        mode: 'x',        // Allow panning in the x direction
        rangeMin: {
            x: null       // Min value of the delay option
        },
        rangeMax: {
            x: null       // Max value of the delay option
        }
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true,    // Enable zooming
        mode: 'x',        // Allow zooming in the x direction
        rangeMin: {
            x: null       // Min value of the duration option
        },
        rangeMax: {
            x: null       // Max value of the duration option
        }
    }
}
```